# refresh dropdownlist after adding a new entry

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application, I have headers dropdownlist, which should refresh after adding a new header.

I tried the below in success of ajax call, but its not working.

```
success: function(data)
{
     alert("Header Added Successfully");
     $('#proj_qn_header_id').selectmenu();
     $('#proj_qn_header_id').selectmenu("refresh");
},
```

select tag in the form

```
 <tr style="height:40px;">
        <td width="35%">
          <%= f.label :header_id,"Header" %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= f.select :header_id,Header.all.collect { |mp| [mp.header, mp.header_id]}, {:prompt=>"Please select"},:id=>"proj_qn_header_id" %>
        </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below code, it worked.

```
success: function(response)
{    
    var newOption = '<option value="' + response + '">' + newHeader + '</option>'
    $('#proj_qn_header_id').append(newOption).selectmenu('refresh');
}
```